# How do I segue from uiviewcontroller to TabBarController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

performSegue(withIdentifier: "m1", sender: self)
The code above is correct here below but it's giving me a SIGBRT (*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'm1'') error claiming the receiver login has no segue with identifier 'm1''
even the login is segued correctly to the UITabBarController with the correct identifier. Forgive me, i'm a beginner developer.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTeGY.png)

Comment: Are you sure that your segue is properly connected in Storyboard?

Also, the code should be `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "m1", sender: self)`

Comment: Yes, the login viewcontroller is segued to the TabBarController.

Comment: Please post the full text of the error message.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<No_Limit_Inc_.invLogin: 0x7f84bfd1bdd0>) has no segue with identifier 'm1''

Comment: Which class is the call to perform the segue in?

Comment: m1 is the segue identifier name and it's UITabBarController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to perform the segue must be in the initial view controller, not the destination view controller. In this case, `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"m1", sender:self)` should be in the UIViewController, and NOT the UITabBarController.